Can this combination of two semi-definite matrices be a non-semi-definite matrix?
Let $A$ and $B$ be two semi-definite matrices. Is there a way to prove that
$$M_{ij} = A_{ij} B_{ij}$$
is also a semi-definite matrix?
Note this is not a regular matrix multiplication. In the case of matrix multiplication one can easily find examples where the multiplication of two semi-definite matrices is not semi-definite.

Schur product theorem.

@user1551 Thanks a lot! I didn't even know this is called Hadamard product.
